# Insert data into SQL Server using VB .NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

i'm trying to insert some sample data into a sql server.

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express.

Here's the code:

```
Public Sub insert()

    Dim myconnect As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    myconnect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DATABASE_NUOVO.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"


    Dim mycommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    mycommand.Connection = myconnect
    mycommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO utenti (nome) VALUES ('mario')"
    myconnect.Open()

    Try
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    myconnect.Close()
    MsgBox("Success")

End Sub
```

The code seems to run correctly, but when i look into the database after running the debug i don't see the sample data.

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Don't restrict your `Catch` to just SqlExceptions.  There are other kinds of exceptions that can be thrown here.

Comment: How should i change the Catch? @RBarryYoung

Comment: INSERT INTO utenti (**nome**) VALUES ('mario') - is that what it is supposed to be, **nome**? Just a thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I've said before on this site - the whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! Visual Studio will be copying around the `.mdf` file and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `Database_Nuovo`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Database_Nuovo;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also: check what the value of the `Copy to Output Directory` property is on your `DATABASE_NUOVO.mdf` file in the `App_Data` directory (find it inside your Visual Studio Solution Explorer).

What might happen (and does, more often than not):

- when Visual Studio starts your app for debugging, it copies `Database_Nuovo.mdf` to the output directory where the app is running (your `.\debug\bin` directory)
- your `INSERT` then runs against this **copy** of the `.mdf` file and works just fine
- you stop debugging and go check the database file again - but this time, you're looking at the `Database_Nuovo.mdf` in the `App_Data` directory --> and **of course** your inserted data **isn't there** since it was inserted into a different file!

Comment: +!: Ah, good one.  I missed that the .mdf could be *copied* rather than moved or renamed (and thus not throw an error).

Comment: Thank you to everybody. The 'error' isn't a real error, simply i was searching my data in the wrong database. My data was in  \debug\bin directory. Sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `Try..Catch` code to handle more error types than just SqlExceptions.  Like this:

```
    Try
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message, , "Sql Exception")
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, , "General Exception")
    End Try
```

SqlExceptions are not the only exceptions that can be thrown here.

Comment: I've change the code but i don't get any type of errors... @RBarryYoung

Comment: Do you get the "Success" message box?

Answer (score 0):

Try with it..

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Try
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DATABASE_NUOVO.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True" //check your connection string carefully whether it points right directory
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table([field1], [field2]) VALUES([Value1], [Value2])" //make sure here your table and column name is exactly like as your database
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table...");
Finally
con.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: I've try your suggestions, but i don't have errors in my sql syntax. @ridoy

Comment: Then it would be a problem of your database file,your insert statement don't work for the database what you put in your connection string.Try the procedure of marc_s first and then apply my code.Expect it would be ok..